# Count the na values per group

Tags: r

In an input data structure

```
data.frame(group = c(1,1,1,2,2,3), number = c(10,NA,10,5,NA,1))
```

How is it possible to count how many NA (missing) values exist for every group number?

Example output

```
group count
1      1
2      1
3      0
```

Comment: Please search before posting many variations on "how to get x by group?" - this sort of issue has typically been covered before.

Answer (score 0):

We can get the `sum` of logical expression by group i.e. `is.na(number)` returns `TRUE` where there are `NA` and `FALSE` for non-NA.  Then get the `sum` of TRUE (TRUE -> 1 and FALSE -> 0)

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    group_by(group) %>% 
    summarise(count = sum(is.na(number)), .groups = 'drop')
```

---

Or use `aggregate` from `base R`

```
aggregate(count ~ group, transform(df1, count = is.na(number)), sum)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(group = c(1,1,1,2,2,3), number = c(10,NA,10,5,NA,1))
```